# Visual Studio Code shortcut to close html tag

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, hotkeys, visual-studio-code, tags

Could you please help, is there any shortcut in Visual Studio Code to complete/close html tags? For example I edit a file:

`<div><p>Some text | <- cursor is here, I press a hotkey and get the </p> closing tag and cursor comes after it. I press the hotkey again and get the </div> closing tag.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Compulim.compulim-vscode-closetag

To close tags without moving cursors or selections, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to execute `closeTag.closeHTMLTagInPlace` command.